# spring mvc how to bypass DispatcherServlet for *.html files?

Tags: servlets, spring-mvc, web.xml

web.xml fragment

```
<!-- Handles all requests into the application -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/app-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

It works fine but I'd like to NOT let the Dispatcher Servlet handle *.html requests. How do I I do that? Thanks.

Comment: This may be of some help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234298/can-springmvc-be-configured-to-process-all-requests-but-exclude-static-content-d

Comment: @AHungerArtist Thanks for the link. I found much better answer in there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Map it on a more specific `url-pattern`.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/spring/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Create a `Filter` which is mapped on `/*`.

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Your Dispatcher Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
<filter-mapping>
```

Which does the following in `doFilter()` method.

```
String uri = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURI();
if (uri.endsWith(".html")) {
    chain.doFilter(request, response); // Just let it go (assuming that files are in real not placed in a /spring folder!)
} else {
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/spring" + uri).forward(request, response); // Pass to Spring dispatcher servlet.
}
```

Comment: This almost works for me... using getRequestURI will return a path including the context-path. Assuming your context is /ctx, a request to /ctx/foo will be dispatched to /ctx/spring/ctx/foo I think getServletPath() + getPathInfo() (if pathInfo != null) works better

Comment: This solve my problem. Thanks BalusC, You're awesome

Answer (score 24):

In Spring MVC 3.x there is the [default servlet handler](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-default-servlet-handler) to take care of this problem.

just add this to the Spring XML config:

```
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
```

Comment: Great. I remember this config but I can't remember exactly the code. Thank you.

Comment: You saved my day. Thank You

Answer (score 2):

```
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

Can catch like `/index` , `/*.html` , `/*.jsp` ...,and give to DispatcherServlet.

```
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
```

Only Can catch `/index`,`/main` ... , without suffix.

Comment: Wow, simplest of all.

Answer (score 2):

Lari's solution (above) is great, and worked for me, but you have to be very careful with the order in which you write the instruction, it has to be in the begining of the document!!!

In my case was something like:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="org.civitana.controller" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your Spring XML config:

```
<!-- This will override the default DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping that is created,
  -  and not map file extensions automagically -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="useDefaultSuffixPattern" value="false"/>
</bean>
```

This will prevent Spring from automatically mapping requests with .html to your controller. E.g. `@RequestMapping(value = "/products/widgets", method = RequestMethod.GET)` would normally trap a URI of `/products/widgets.html` as well as `/products/widgets`. Adding the above XML forces exact matching of URI patterns by Spring (only the latter will match).