# Getting 404 when adding a JS file to a JSP file using spring

Tags: javascript, jsp, spring-mvc

I am pretty new to Spring MVC and I am trying to "include" a JS file in the JSP.

My Folder structure is:

```
webapp
- WEB-INF
- scripts
- META-INF
- - jsp
- - - myFile.jsp
```

I am trying to include a js file from scripts folder in myFile.jsp with the following code:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Highstock Example</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/scripts/1.js" />"></script>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function()
            {...
```

And I am trying to use the code in 1.js.

And here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>Spring3-Hibernate</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>list.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!--<context-param>-->
        <!--<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>-->
        <!--<param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>-->
    <!--</context-param>-->

    <!--<listener>-->
        <!--<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>-->
    <!--</listener>-->



</web-app>
```

The problem is that when hitting the desired page the JSP loads but I am getting 404 in the firebug since the browser cannot access 1.js. (I have checked and the file is there :)

Any advice will help, 
Thanks

Comment: What path is generated for the js in the html view source?

Answer (score 0):

You spring controller processing all your requests:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

So your 1.js and all other files will go to spring servlet dispatcher. And you do not have mapping for this url: controller or view resolver or static resource mapping.

Comment: Here is a similar question to exclude the static resource. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234298/can-springmvc-be-configured-to-process-all-requests-but-exclude-static-content