# spring mvc website on  root ("/")

Tags: java, servlets, spring-mvc, mapping

I want to map spring mvc controller to root (`/**`) path (and not sub-folder such as "/something") while making exceptions with `mvc:resources` (open to another method).

This should be the ABC of that framework but apparently is a very complicated stuff to ask of it.

My `app-servlet.xml` has these obvious mapping exceptions:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/favicon.ico" location="/favicon.ico" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/robots.txt" location="/robots.txt" />
```

And I have this controller:

```
import java.util.Date;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/**")
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String service(final HttpServletRequest request) {
        final String servlet_path = request.getServletPath();
        System.out.println(String.format("%s %s", new Date().toString(), servlet_path));
        return "test";
    }
}
```

Now when I hit "/" or "/test" or "/test/page" I get output like:

```
Fri Aug 03 00:22:12 IDT 2012 /
Fri Aug 03 00:22:13 IDT 2012 /favicon.ico
```

.. see? `service()` is being called for `/favicon.ico` even when it's explicitly excluded!

Now I guess there's some "priority" to the `@Controller` over the XML, still, how do I make the exclusion work?

A simple requirement - have the website on "/".

P.S [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4556267/286260) answers to a very similar question.

Another note: This question is not about tomcat context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue here is that the underlying [HandlerMapping](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerMapping.html) registered with `<mvc:resources` has a very low priority compared to the one registered with `<mvc:annotation-driven/>`. If you requirement is to simply have something respond to "/" a better way probably will be to have a different @RequestMapping than `/**` instead say have it as `/home` and define something along these lines:

`<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="home" />`

If this will not work, the only other option will be to lower the priority of underlying handlerMapping of `<mvc:resources`, which can be done by explicitly defining the HandlerMapping - a little complicated but can be done.

**Updated**
Here is a possible configuration:

Try with just this first:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/favicon.ico" location="/favicon.ico" order="0"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/robots.txt" location="/robots.txt" order="0"/>
```

If this alone does not work, change `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` to something along these lines for Spring 3.1.x:

```
<bean name="handlerAdapter" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="webBindingInitializer">
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.bind.support.ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer">
            <property name="conversionService" ref="conversionService"></property>
            <property name="validator">
                <bean class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
                    <property name="providerClass" value="org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator"></property>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.XmlAwareFormHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean name="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping">
    <property name="order" value="2"></property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Your solution refers to a single URL ("/" -> "home"). I need it to be be a wild-card. If you could generously elaborate on HOW TO raise `mvc:resources`'s priority over `@RequestMapping` then that would, I'm guessing, solve it. Thank you!

Comment: That only works if your home page doesn't require a controller action (thus is just a view file being displayed, like a Welcome page ..., no fancy logic). If you need to use a page that requires some controller action to do stuff before you get to the view, you can use a redirect `<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="redirect:home" />`. That will redirect to the `home` view, which will then call the HomeController, or however you name your controller.

Comment: I followed your answer but I cannot access it yet. My question is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32302465/i-cannot-access-robots-txt-in-spring-mvc

Answer (score 8):

I'd like to clarify that instead of rewriting the `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` one can change the declaration order of the handler directives:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/favicon.ico" location="/favicon.ico" order="0"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/robots.txt" location="/robots.txt" order="0"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```