# Annotation Configuration Replacement for mvc:resources - Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, configuration

I'm trying to upgrade my spring mvc project to utilize the new annotations and get rid of my xml. Previously I was loading my static resources in my `web.xml` with the line:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

Now, I'm utilizing the `WebApplicationInitializer` class and `@EnableWebMvc` annotation to startup my service without any xml files, but can't seem to figure out how to load my resources.

Is there an annotation or new configuration to pull these resources back in without having to use xml?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

**For Spring 3 & 4:**

One way to do this is to have your configuration class extend `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`, then override the following method as such:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}
```

Comment: This answer is totally correct. However, if you're having issues (like I was) after adding this, remember that you might still need a default servlet handler described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17013442/2047962

Comment: Upvoted for the answer. Better if you can add explanation. That would be nice for a beginner.

Comment: @Menuka Explaination: Every request which begins with "/resources/**" path will be mapped to a files in a "/resources/" folder.

Answer (score 25):

### Spring 5

As of Spring 5, the correct way to do this is to simply implement the [WebMvcConfigurer](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer.html) interface.

For example:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MyApplication implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
}
```

See deprecated message in: [WebMvcConfigurerAdapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.html)