# Backround image not appearing when i try to insert it in Spring Mvc

Tags: java, html, spring

I am trying to build a weather Scraper website using Spring MVC. For now, i am trying to make the design of the website. When, i try to insert a background image for this design, it does not seem to appear when i check out the URL(http://localport:8080/weatherScraper). However, the rest of the elements appear as expected.

My Controller class:

public class Controller {

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/weatherScraper", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String webpageGet(ModelMap modelMap){
    return "Mainpage";
}
```

}

[My MainPage.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRWgo.png)

I saved the image as weather.jpg. I even tried <body background = "weather.jpg"  and <body style="background-image:url("weather.jpg")" and I tried a lot of other different ways but it still did not work for me. Can someone help me out on this please?

Comment: Refer to the link, it can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20369529/display-image-in-jsp-with-spring-mvc/20369698

Comment: The link you sent above suggests that i add <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" /> to the mvc configuartion but what exactly does mvc configuration mean? In which file do i exactly put this?

Comment: In your spring mvc application, there will be a web.xml, Refer spring documentation

Comment: i dont have a web.xml

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14861720/annotation-configuration-replacement-for-mvcresources-spring for java based configuration

Comment: Nothing seems to work for me, i created the webmvc configuartion class and added @Override
public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
} ...... i even added <body background="<c:url value='/resources/images/weather3.jpg>"> in my html file but nothing works. Please help me with this asap

Comment: Have you added weather3.jpg to your resources folder in your project

Comment: Yes i have added weather3.jpg in a directory called images in rthe resources folder

Comment: I've literally tried everything possible but nothing seems to work for me. Can someone please help.