# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/resources/css/styles.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'SpringDispatcher'

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am developing simple web application using Spring MVC. Could you please point me out why the resources are not rendered on the page when I am accessing it? The whole page is being rendered however.

Here my project structure

[image]

I am receiving the following warning:

```
No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/resources/css/styles.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'SpringDispatcher'
```

JSP page that holds the links to the resources:

```
includes.jsp

<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

<c:set var="base" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>

<link href="<c:url value="${base}/resources/css/pure/pure-min.css" />" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="<c:url value="${base}/resources/css/styles.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="<c:url value="${base}/resources/css/menu.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="${base}/resources/js/validateInput.js"></script>
```

JSP page that has to be rendered:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<html>
<head>
    <jsp:include page="/resources/includes.jsp"/>
</head>
<body>

<div id="main-container">
    <div class="site-content">

        <h1 class="fueling-header">Registration</h1>

        <form class="pure-form pure-form-aligned"
              action="/register"
              method="post"
              onsubmit="return validateUserInput();">



            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my `WebAppInitializer` code:

```
public class WebAppContextInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext annotationConfigWebApplicationContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        annotationConfigWebApplicationContext.register(WebContextConfiguration.class);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet(
                "SpringDispatcher",new DispatcherServlet(annotationConfigWebApplicationContext)
        );
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }
}
```

`ContextConfiguration` class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@Import(ServiceContextConfiguration.class)
@ComponentScan("controllers")
public class WebContextConfiguration {

public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
.addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}

    @Bean(name = "view_resolver")
    public InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

        internalResourceViewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        internalResourceViewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return internalResourceViewResolver;
    }
}
```

And my simple controller

```
@Controller
public class BasicController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/greeting")
    public String sayBasic(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("greeting", "Hello world");
        return "register";
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try adding static resource handlers like they're described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14299149/how-to-use-spring-mvcs-mvcresources-tag-in-a-java-application-context

Comment: Thank you for suggesting it. I will try to use them and let you know ASAP.

Comment: @DennisHunziker, nope. It didn't help me. See my update.

Comment: can you provide your JSP/HTML code ?

Comment: @VA31 updated my post

Comment: What I could notice is that ${base} is not adding any value. So can you hardcode ${base} to your project contextPath to check whether that works at least ?

Comment: I have already done it.

Comment: So What is the value of ${base} ? Can you print to console./log ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had the cyclic reference in another controller i.e. the get method and post were mapped to the same logical view name. My configuration was correct.

For those who will meet the same problem: remove all request mappings and add them step by step till you will see where the problem occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Remove ${base} as it is adding additional / Character.