# Exclude url from mvc dispatcher

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Is there a way for some specific urls to be excluded from being intercepted by the spring mvc controller?

web.xml

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="getState.jsp", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Map<String,? extends Object> loadStates() {
```

.......     }

Now if I request index.jsp,it would say 'No mapping found' and the page would not be rendered.
What's the best practice to avoid this situation in annotation-based deployments?

Comment: This thread might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234298/can-springmvc-be-configured-to-process-all-requests-but-exclude-static-content

Answer (score 2):

The general way of excluding certain URLs from being intercepted by the dispatcher servlet is by adding this:

```
 <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>  
   <url-pattern>URLYouWantToExclude</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

This should work in Tomcat and Jetty.

Comment: Do you mean to say that default overrides all other servlets defined?

Comment: The more specific URL takes precedence AFAIK.

Comment: I am sorry, but I didn't get the exact purpose of doing this.